# what is the nameserver for my domain name if the domain name points to my self-hosting server?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-registration

1. I bought an domain name, `mydomain.com`.
2. I have a public static IP, `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.
3. My IIS server runnning on the static IP and I can access it via the IP (not the domain name).

In the domain name control panel there is 2 text boxes for nameservers. What should I put there?

Answer (score 1):

If your DNS is resolving properly then it sounds like you need to enter the URL into the Virtual Server for that site, not the NS entries.

Comment: +1 @Jonathan: I have no idea what Virtual Server is. I am a newbie, could you explain it in a simpler and easy-to-understand sentence?

Comment: Sure, there's a lot of jargon surrounding "vhosts" and "virtual servers". Essentially instead of your browser asking for an IP address these days it asks for a URL like www.business.com. Your Web Server needs to know which file to serve for www.business.com and that's one of the reasons that each site must have a Virtual Server. Hopefully this old article will help a bit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816576